# Atom Script package for AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm am completely a noobie when it comes to using Atom and programming in general but I've been getting my feet wet with AutoHotKey recently (previously have some super beginner experience with Python). I've loved using Atom and came across the [Script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package which says it supports AHK.

When I try to run an ahk script, however, I get:

> "'AutoHotKey' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

I already have the requisite language package installed.

In reading through Script's information it has a table with the header "Required in PATH", underneath of which it says AutoHotKey.exe. I suspect this has something to do with why I am unable to get it to work, but being completely uneducated in what they even means leaves me scratching my head.

Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey` (assuming you installed it in the default location) to your system/user's PATH environment variable. This folder should contain `AutoHotKey.exe`.

### For All Users on Your Computer

1. Open the **Start Menu** or click the **Windows Search** icon
2. Type `Advanced System Settings`
3. Select *View Advanced System Settings* (or similar)
4. Click the **Environment Variables...** button
5. In the *lower* list of variables (labelled *System variables*), select **Path**
6. Click the *lower* **Edit...** button
7. On the right-hand side, click **New**
8. Add the install directory for AHK, e.g. `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey`
9. Click **OK** on all 3 dialogs.
10. Restart Atom

### For Only Your User on Your Computer

1. Open the **Start Menu** or click the **Windows Search** icon
2. Type `Advanced System Settings`
3. Select *View Advanced System Settings* (or similar)
4. Click the **Environment Variables...** button
5. In the *upper* list of variables (labelled *User variables for <USER>*), select **Path**
6. Click the *upper* **Edit...** button
7. On the right-hand side, click **New**
8. Add the install directory for AHK, e.g. `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey`
9. Click **OK** on all 3 dialogs.
10. Restart Atom